# How to get rid of spam that sends from clients own email address?

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, virus

I've Googled everywhere for a solution for this, but though the same issue appears to be happening to a lot of people, I havent found anything that helped.

Several of my clients are receiving loads of spam emails with the senders email being their own.

The emails subject line is:

> Environmental corporation searching for representatives worldwide.

The emails are not being sent from any scripts in the sites and all the code appears clean.

I have also updated the sites CMS.

Would anyone know how to get round this issue? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't do much for it other then making sure you've got SPF records, etc, set up to help identify their actual emails as legit. That makes filtering the ones that aren't easier to do. But there's nothing you can do to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set SPF records to achieve this.

I generated an SPF record in each accounts CPANEL and added it to the TXT record field in my domain names registrars console.

Answer (score 0):

I filtered on the word "Environmental" as they all seem to have that word in common in the Subject
Cheers,
Barry